# Getting node from a graph prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm a newbie in Prolog, I have this question.
From this fact need getting every single node from this nodelist, how I can do?

```
nodelist([[a,[2,3],[b,d]],[b,[5,1],[a,c,d]],[c,[3,2],[b,d]]).

where nodelist([[node,[coordinate_node],[neighbours]]])
```

I've tried

```
node(Nodelist,Node):- nodelist(Nodelist), findall(Node,Nodelist(Nodes),Nodes).
```

> syntax error operator expected

Comment: I think that what you want is **nodelist(Nodelist), findall(Node,member([Node,_,_], Nodelist),Nodes).** but you don't get all nodes !

Comment: yes, i think this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I show you two ways to do the job :
First way, "functionnal design" because you work with every element of the list of nodes

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
nodelist([[a,[2,3],[b,d]],[b,[5,1],[a,c,d]],[c,[3,2],[b,d]]]).

fetch_nodes(In, Out) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^(X = [_, _, Nodes], union(Y,Nodes, Z)), In, [], Out).
```

example

```
?- nodelist(L), fetch_nodes(L, Nodes).
L = [[a, [2, 3], [b, d]], [b, [5, 1], [a, c, d]], [c, [3, 2], [b, d]]],
Nodes = [a, c, b, d].
```

The second way is more "prologish", **aggregate_all** extends **findall** :

```
nodes(Nodelist,Nodes):-
   aggregate_all(set(Node), (member([_, _, L], Nodelist), member(Node, L)),Nodes).
```

PS You can find details for **library lambda**, **foldl**, **union** and **aggregate_all** on the site of [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program. Note that I had to fix your definition of `nodelist/1`.

```
nodelist([[a,[2,3],[b,d]],[b,[5,1],[a,c,d]],[c,[3,2],[b,d]]]).

node(X) :-
    nodelist(L),
    member([X,_,_], L).

nodes(Xs) :-
    nodelist(L),
    nodes(L, Xs).

nodes([], []).
nodes([[X,_,_]|L], [X|Xs]) :-
    nodes(L, Xs).
```

and now:

```
?- node(X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c.

?- nodes(Xs).
Xs = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: User9213>> d is not present ! You should ork with list of neighbours of each node

Comment: @joel76 maybe. The question is silent on the matter.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear and in fact my intention was to tease only the element at the top of the every list.But now that I've read joel76 's answer I can say that this is the best solution, the one I should have been looking for. Thanks anyway @user9213